# How to Open one Accordin By Default when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I'm using below code for my mobile website where on Selecting the Accordin will show it's contents. I'd like to load a first Accordin to load and show by Default as the user loads the page. How can I achieve that one.

Here is the Html File

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
        body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color:#fafafa;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 150px auto;
    }
    h3 {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>

<link href="src/ziehharmonika.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="ziehharmonika">
        <h3>Section One</h3>
        <div>
            <iframe src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-5.jpg" height="600px" width="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
        <h3>Section Two</h3>
        <div>
            <iframe src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-5.jpg" height="600px" width="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
        <h3>Section Three</h3>
        <div>
            <iframe src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-5.jpg" height="600px" width="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the Script file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/ziehharmonika.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ziehharmonika').ziehharmonika({
        collapsible: true,
        prefix: '★'
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _ gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Any Help would be much mmore appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to make an online version with [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) .

Try this:

```
 <div class="ziehharmonika">
    <h3 class="active">Section One</h3>
    <div style="display:block;">
        <iframe src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-5.jpg" height="600px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    <h3>Section Two</h3>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-5.jpg" height="600px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    <h3>Section Three</h3>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-5.jpg" height="600px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes you are right, I should do that from now on .and yes it actually works but not completely. It highlights the tab i.e make active but dosen't show the content and only when clicked shows what it is hiding. what should I do now.

Comment: Replace `<iframe>` with another tag like `<p>` with some plain text and see the result.

Comment: nope still not working here is the link of images https://ibb.co/noOyHF, it just only make a tab active but show contents only if clicked.

Comment: Can you inspect the element content's wrapper?  It should have `display:block`

Comment: I looked for block but all in vain, couldn't find like same. Here is the sample file, could you please have a look at it https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2j3ckof7nFGWFNaeTc1OTJMY1U

Comment: As I told you before it's work with `display:block`  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By8dll8XxkSNWmtqYy1MNXpRcm8

Comment: oh yes. My apologizes. Thank you for your kind effort. It works perfectly.